# Need to get Linux Dist name from different Dists

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, debian, redhat

want to code a script that is for multiple linux distributions. 
Also want to add commands that check, and if not exist install some packages.. So, need a  solution to ckeck Dist name (like Debian or RedHat) to execute the right command for this Dist. 
I have tryed "`lsb_release`" but is this working all the follow dists? : `Debian / Ubuntu | Red Hat / Fedora / Suse / Cent OS`" If yes, any idea where i can get the `lsb_release` output from all the Dists above?

in Debian I get this from `lsb_release -a 2>/dev/null | grep Distributor`:

`Distributor ID:    Debian`

at Rasberry, I get this:

`Distributor ID:    Raspbian`

but what about other Distributions?

Comment: Have you tried `cat /proc/version`?

Comment: @dps That gives the version of the kernel, which isn't related to the distribution name. (In some situations, it may even be explicitly out of sync -- for instance, if the machine is running in certain virtualized environments.)

Comment: @dps `/proc/version` doesn't show me the Distribution. @duskwuff allready wrote it, its just the kernel version. But I need the Dist Name.. Thought the `lsb_release` cmd is a standard linux cmd, for all Dists, but i'm not sure

Comment: It is very difficult to develop something like that which will work for all those distributions. I think your best bet is to develop 2-3 tests which cover all distributions, and on your script you would "test" each one of those tests for the keywords, such as `if [ -z "$myTest" ]; then...` and/or `echo "$myTest" | grep -i debian ...`

Comment: Sounds like you really need an automation solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `lsb_release` should print the distribution information after installing the required package.

e,g:

On debian based distro:

```
apt-get install lsb-release
```

On RHEL based distro:

```
yum install redhat-lsb-core
```

or

```
yum install redhat-lsb
```

Alernative method : You can get the distribution information through:

On debian based disto

```
cat /proc/version
cat /etc/issue
cat /etc/issue.net
cat /etc/lsb-release
cat /etc/os-release
```

On RHEL based distro :

```
cat /proc/version
cat /etc/centos-release
cat /etc/lsb-release
cat /etc/redhat-release
cat /etc/system-release
```

Answer (score 1):

seems that all modern linux distributions have [/etc/os-release](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html) file with ID=distribution (unfortunately have no Raspberry around to test).

Comment: RASBERRY: `PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs" `

Comment: the `ID_LIKE=debian` is interesting... unfortunately i do no have any redhat/centod ect linux installed to test it.. i think on Ubuntu should get same ID_LIKE as in Rasbian = debian

Comment: NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

Comment: Thanks for support! I see `ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"` sounds like ReadHat "dist"... mean, fedora is based on RedHat?

Comment: "The Fedora Project was founded on 22 September 2003 when Red Hat decided to split Red Hat Linux into Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) and a community-based operating system, Fedora" [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Project)